# Socket.io doesn't work with on event ("connection")

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

i want to use `socket-io` in my project and i established it on the server (`node-js`) and
the client (`react`) but it seems doesn't work fine and in console on the server i can't see `user connected` when user connected.

app.js (server):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

(async () => {
  await mongoConnect(error => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
        console.log(`server is running on ${PORT} port`)
      );

      const io = require("./utils/socket-io/socket-io").initialSocket(server);

      io.on("connection", socket => {
        console.log("user connected");
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

socket-io.js (server):

```
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

let io;

module.exports = {
  initialSocket: server => {
    io = socketIo(server);
    return io;
  },
  getIo: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error("no connection to socket-io");
    }

    return io;
  }
};
```

posts.js (client):

```
import socketIo from "socket.io-client";

  useEffect(() => {
    socketIo("http://localhost:5000");
  }, [socketIo]);
```

Comment: the event is connect,  io.on('connect')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2822041/someone-special i tried it but doesn't work too

Comment: `connection` is an alias of `connect`. I think he might need to start the server by calling `listen()` after binding it to the io server.

Comment: sounds like you got it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/209067/pablo i changed it but nothing happen

Comment: Did you checked browser dev tools for any polling errors from socket?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2822041/someone-special yeah i think every thing is all right but i don't know what's is wrong here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704323/piyush-rana oh i see those error now. error is `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NONu_gk' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` looks like a cors error .right?? i use cors package to menage that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704323/piyush-rana i found the solution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `app.js` to this

```
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);         // This is going to allow us to create a new web server for express and we're going to it to our express application

const io = socketio(server);                   // Configure socketio to work with a given server
                                               // Now the server supports websockets


(async () => {
  await mongoConnect(error => {
    ...
    
    else {
      io.on("connection", socket => {
        console.log("user connected");
      });

      server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`));
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891406/kshewengger i edited but nothing changed